Is the uniform limit of "almost eikonal" maps eikonal?
Let $f_n: \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R$ be continuously differentiable functions with $f_n \to f$ uniformly for some $f$.
Suppose that $|\nabla f_n| \to 1$ uniformly. Is it true that $f$ is $C^1$ with $\nabla f = v$ for some unit vector $v \in \mathbb R^d$?
Remark: The case with all $f_n$ identically equal to $f$ reduces to the following statement - if $f$ is $C^1$ with $|\nabla f| = 1$ everywhere, then $\nabla f = v$ for some unit vector $v$. That is, the only global $C^1$ solutions to the eikonal equation are planes. This is true, though not immediate to prove.

Yes, and the proof is pretty much the same as for the exact eikonal equation.
Without loss of generality, $f_n(0)=0$ for all $n$.
Start from $0$ and go along the gradient of $f_n$ for large but fixed time $T$ in both directions, i.e., solve $x_n'(t)=\nabla f_n(x_n(t))$ on $[-T,T]$ with $x_n(0)=0$. Then $|x_n(T)|,|x_n(-T)|\le (1+\varepsilon)T$ but $f_n(x_n(T))\ge(1-\varepsilon)T$ and $f_n(x_n(-T))\le -(1-\varepsilon)T$, so $|x_n(T)-x_n(-T)|\ge 2[(1-\varepsilon)/(1+\varepsilon)]T$. This implies (for fixed large $T$ and $\varepsilon\to 0$) that $x_n(T)$ and $x_n(-T)$ are almost exactly opposites of each other, both are at the distance nearly $T$ from the origin, and the values of $f_n$ at them are almost $T$ and $-T$ correspondingly.
Now, passing to a subsequence, we can assume that they converge to a pair of opposite points at the distance $T$ from the origin. Let $v_T$ be the unit vector in the corresponding direction, so our pair is $-Tv_T,Tv_T$ and $f(Tv_T)=T, f(-Tv_T)=-T$. Now for every $|x|<T^{1/4}$, say, we have $|Tv_T-x|=T-(x,v_T)+O(T^{-1/2})$ and $|-Tv_T-x|=T+(x,v_T)+O(T^{-1/2})$. Since $f$ is $1$-Lipschitz, it follows that $|f(x)-(x,v_T)|=O(T^{-1/2})$ in the disk centered at the origin and of radius $T^{1/4}$. Letting $T\to\infty$ and passing to a subsequence such that $v_T\to v$, we get $f(x)=(x,v)$, as required.

Really nice, interesting that you have to take $T \to \infty$. I guess the idea is that you maximally stretch a line and this forces the property of being a plane locally and hence everywhere, or something... Just one question, how do we know that the limit $v$ is independent of $x$?

Oh never mind, you started from $0$ instead, none of the choices you made depended on $x$. This makes the proof method even more interesting.
